# Magento 2: add existing attribute to product

Tags: magento2, product, attributes

I have a question, is there a way to add existing attributes to new product? I have some attributes already created in my admin panel and want to add them programmatically , I guess there should be something  like this in Product Factory

```
$_product->setAttribute("Attribute or value of the attribute");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below method to update product attribute value.

```
$product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);
$product->setData($attributeCode, $attributeValue2);
$this->productRepository->save($product);
```

Also, if you want `$objectManager` method to create a script. You can do it by following below code snippet.

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

// Set the state. You can also set "adminhtml"
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

// Get the first product of a collection
$products = $obj->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
foreach ($products as $p) {
    $p->setData($attributeCode, $attributeValue);
    $p->getResource()->saveAttribute($p, $attributeCode);
}
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Thank you! How can I add more than one attribute? can I use this method more than twice? $product->setData($attributeCode, $attributeValue2);

Comment: Thank you it works even with more than 1 attribute code, $product->setData($attributeCode1, $attributeValue1);  $product->setData($attributeCode2, $attributeValue2); works perfectly fine. Greetings!

Comment: Good to hear... you're welcome...